# Test Connection and loop if true or false (change colors...)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make this script here test the connection to an IP and then change the color+output with the result so if the result is true then green with "Works" or what ever and if the result is false then red.

Also, while in green if the state of the connections changes to false then change the color to red (same of course for red, change color to green when the connection is true again).

I just want to ping IP and see all the time if I can reach them.

```
function TestCon {
    Test-Connection $ipadr -Count 1 -Quiet
}
function ConOK {
    while (TestCon) {
        Write-Host -BackgroundColor green -ForegroundColor black REACHED
    }
}
function ConBad {
    while (TestCon -eq False) {
        Write-Host -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White REACHED
    }
}

$ipadr = Read-Host -prompt 'IP?'
while (1 -eq 1) {
    if (TestCon -eq True) {
        ConOK
    } else {
        ConBad
    }
}
```

As far as I undestand this my code goes to `ConOK` and as soon as the connection is disabled (False) it ends the code.
I also used `1 -eq 1` to make it infinite? But I think I'm going some wrong way here and would really be happy if someone could help me out and explain this a little.

I want to repeat my loop all the time and change the output with the current state of `Test-Connection`. Here is what I mean:

[image: Flowchart]

Please reopen.

Comment: [1] you are testing against `True` or `False` - a [string] object. [*grin*] that really otta be `$True` or `$False`. ///// [2] you are testing in the main `while` loop AND in another `while` loop in each `Con*` function. why? ///// [3] you really otta use a delay - otherwise this will run an entire core to max. it's highly unlikely you need more than once every few seconds ... and once per minute may well be enuf.

Comment: There are enterprise monitoring tools specifically for this purpose. SCOM for example or HP OpenView. Why do this, this way. As a best practice, forever loops are really not a thing.  Take a look at this article for a novel approach. "https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/6308/ultimate-powershell-telemetry-prompt". Tweaking this approach, one could attach this to a scheduled task as well to display state on a schedule.

Comment: I know that there is free tools for stuff like this, I use Zabbix daily but I want to do something for fun for me to learn and experience.

Comment: @postanote I don't think I could hate anyone enough to recommend SCOM to them ...

Comment: @Stefan.D It was already clear what you want the code to do. Please read my answer to the linked question to understand why your code will not do what you expect, and what you need to do to fix it. Besides, you're making this way too complicated. Something like this would suffice: `while ($true) {if (Test-Connection ...) {Write-Host ...} else {Write-Host ...}}`.

Comment: Ansgar... ''I don't think I could hate anyone enough to recommend SCOM to them',   ;-}  Yeppers is has its issues (well System Center is a huge thing and really requires commitment - trust me I've had to deal with it), hence why I gave two. BTW, not a real fan of HPOV either, as I had to deal with that as well. There were a couple of others in my time as well. everything has it's good a bad and one has to weigh that for themselves.